# Is there an efficient way to fill a numba `Dict` in parallel?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, parallel-processing, numba

I'm having some trouble quickly filling a numba `Dict` object with key-value pairs (around 63 million of them). Is there an efficient way to do this in parallel?

The documentation (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-dict) is clear that `numba.typed.Dict` is not thread-safe, and so I think to use `prange` with a single `Dict` object would be a bad idea. I've tried to use a numba `List` of `Dict`s, to populate them in parallel and then stitch them together using `update`, but I think this last step is also inefficient.

Note that one thing (which may be important) is that all the keys are unique, i.e. once assigned, a key will not be reassigned a value. I think this property makes the problem amenable to an efficient parallelised solution.

Below is an example of the serial approach, which is slow with a large number of key-value pairs.

```
d = typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.UnicodeCharSeq(128), value_type=types.int64
)

@njit
def fill_dict(keys_list, values_list, d):

    n = len(keys_list)
    for i in range(n):
        d[keys_list[i]] = values_list[i]


fill_dict(keys_list, values_list, d)
```

Can anybody help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: I doubt there is a way. Lockfree hash tables are a rare breed and usually more suited to parallel lookup with occasional insertion, not filling. Numba's dict uses the same algorithm as Python's dict and that cannot parallelize insertion easily. If your keys were highly redundant, you could use one dict per thread to filter out the redundant keys but since that is not the case, I doubt there is much you can do here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to stitch them together if you preprocess the key into an integer that can be computed for its modulo num_shard value.

```
# assuming hash() returns an arbitrary integer computed by ascii values
shard = hash(key) % num_shard;
selected_dictionary = dictionary[shard]
value = selected_dictionary[key]

# inserting
# lock only the selected_dictionary
shard = hash(key) % num_shard;
selected_dictionary = dictionary[shard]
selected_dictionary.push((key,value))
```

The hashing could be something like sum of all ascii codes of chars in key. The modulo based indexing separates blocks of keys so that they can work independently without extra processing except hashing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...what a nice idea! I'll give it a go and let you know whether I can get it working.

Comment: For a unified memory system of multiple GPUs, it may work but if its not unified memory, then you should also explicitly select the GPU device from the shard index (considering shards are balanced).